# mysql binlog error "ERROR: Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'Found invalid event in binary log', data_len: 341, event_type: 2 **"

Tags: centos, mysql

I am new in mysql  binary log and replication .Please help me sort this issue.

I am using mysql version 5.0.95 and now facing errors in binlogs. Some of querries in binary log  as unknown event and also getting error when we try to force read the binary log using mysqlbinlog utility

```
mysqlbinlog techgv3_mysql-bin.000001  > /dev/null
```

Command output

```
ERROR: Error in Log_event::read_log_event(): 'Found invalid event in binary log', data_len: 341, event_type: 2
Could not read entry at offset 126:Error in log format or read error
```

I have tested mysqlbinlog utility with different version . But no luck . same error . A lot of unknown events .

Os version : CentOS release 6.4 (Final) 64 bit

Command output

```
mysqlbinlog -f techgv3_mysql-bin.000001
#131212 17:21:42 server id 100  end_log_pos 112256 
# Unknown event
# at 112256
#131212 17:21:42 server id 100  end_log_pos 112284         Intvar
SET INSERT_ID=13826501/*!*/;
# at 112284
#131212 17:21:42 server id 100  end_log_pos 112636 
# Unknown event
# at 112636
#131212 17:21:42 server id 100  end_log_pos 112664         Intvar
SET INSERT_ID=13826502/*!*/;
# at 112664
#131212 17:21:42 server id 100  end_log_pos 113873 
# Unknown event
# at 113873
#131212 17:21:43 server id 100  end_log_pos 113901         Intvar
SET INSERT_ID=13826503/*!*/;
# at 113901
#131212 17:21:43 server id 100  end_log_pos 114256 
# Unknown event
# at 114256
#131212 17:21:43 server id 100  end_log_pos 114443 
# Unknown event
# at 114443
#131212 17:21:43 server id 100  end_log_pos 114471         Intvar
SET INSERT_ID=13826504/*!*/;
# at 114471
#131212 17:21:43 server id 100  end_log_pos 114818 
# Unknown event
# at 114818
#131212 17:21:43 server id 100  end_log_pos 114846         Intvar
SET INSERT_ID=13826505/*!*/;
# at 114846
#131212 17:21:43 server id 100  end_log_pos 115404 
# Unknown event
# at 115404
```

Also created same mysql version 5.0.95  in my local system and execute all mysql query from general log of server.Can't find any error in binary log ?

Have any idea how to sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solution is simple. Upgrade your `mysql-client`.

The binlogs were created using a different version `mysql` server. This usually happens when you copied the binary from remote server or, inside docker container. make your `mysqlbinlong` utility version is same not the `mysql` server version.